# how to disable select option to grow in size automatically?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

The select option grows automatically in my mobile app based on the size of the string how do i restrict it so that it will be fixed in a size and also the characters in there will be displayed completely(small font is okay).

Problem: I want to limit the size based on the screen size and not allow horizontal/'vertical scrolling in my app

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" >
            <fieldset class="ui-field-contain" data-role="controlgroup">

  <select>
  <option></option>
  <!-- etc -->
  </select>

  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply CSS to a "select" element to ensure it is a constant size.

Add the following to "head" (if you don't already have an imported CSS file):

```
<style>
    select {
        width:300px;
    }
</style>
```

You can set the width to whatever you would like.

If you want to support very large strings in a small space without scrolling, you have no choice but to shrink the font. It would probably make more sense to keep all of the fonts the same size rather than to have a variety in the same select box, so you can simply add this to your "style" element:

```
select {
    width:300px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

...or however large you want the font to be.

Your container should be adjusted in size as well. You should give it an "id" or "class" and then I suggest you apply "max-width" to it:

```
<div id="select-container" data-role="fieldcontain" >
    <fieldset class="ui-field-contain" data-role="controlgroup">
        <select>
            <option></option>
            <!-- etc -->
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
#select-container {
    max-width:300px;
}
```

...or however big you want the container to be. Using "max-width", the minimum width of the container should be at a little bigger than the size of the "select" it contains.